# Правильный код для задания из Задание class Car по ООП из книги «Программирование на Java для детей, родителей, бабушек и дедушек"

Tags: java

Это задание из книги «Программирование на Java для детей, родителей, бабушек и дедушек».

Выдаёт следующую ошибку в классе `CarOwner` - см. код ниже

> The value of the local variable `ourDistance` is not used

Программа компилируется, но как убрать эту рекомендацию?

```java
public class CarOwner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car myCar = new Car();
        myCar.start();
        
        int ourDistance = 0; //**The value of the local variable ourDistance is not used**
        ourDistance = myCar.drive(0);
        ourDistance = myCar.drive(1);
        ourDistance = myCar.drive(2);
        
        myCar.stop();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Car {
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Let's go!");
    }
    
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("We arrived!");
    }
    
    public int drive(int howlong) {
        int distance = howlong * 60;
        System.out.println( "We passed " + distance + " meters");
        return distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"но как убрать эту рекомендацию?"* --- ну вы переведите сообщение на русский... Что оно говорит?

Comment: перевёл, сначала не понял, а потом в итоге догадался, что по факту это лишний параметр.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В представленном коде значение переменной `ourDistance` *переприсваивается* несколько раз, и НЕ используется ни для чего больше (хотя бы для вывода значения переменной в консоли).

Если целью кода было вычислить пробег *и показать* результат *после каждого вызова* в методе `drive`, то переменная вообще была не нужна:

```java
System.out.println("Пробег после 0 часов: " + myCar.drive(0));
System.out.println("Пробег после 1 часов: " + myCar.drive(1));
```

но даже в таком случае следовало воспользоваться циклом.

Вероятно, переменную следовало завести для вычисления общего (суммарного) пробега:

```java
int ourDistance = 0;

ourDistance += myCar.drive(0);
System.out.println("Cуммарный пробег после 0 часов: " + ourDistance);
ourDistance += myCar.drive(1);
System.out.println("Cуммарный пробег после 1 часов: " + ourDistance);
ourDistance += myCar.drive(2);
System.out.println("Cуммарный пробег после 2 часов: " + ourDistance);
```

Comment: Спасибо! До циклов ещё рановато, вы верно подметили, что переменная ourDistance больше ни где не используется и соответственно подчеркивалась как "лишняя"

Answer (score 0):

Параметр

> int ourDistance = 0

оказался лишний. Пытался сделать по книжке...

В итоге вот корректно:

```java
public class CarOwner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car myCar = new Car();
        myCar.start();
        
        myCar.drive(0);
        myCar.drive(1);
        myCar.drive(2);

        myCar.stop();
    }
}
```